# Deployment on payara with cargo plugin

Tags: deployment, maven-2, payara, cargo-maven2-plugin

i want to deploy my War with cargo-maven2-plugin but its not work like expected.
when i deploy the first time, its works, but when i deploy a second time i got an error after undeploy is executed.

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.16:redeploy (deploy) on project XXX-deploy: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.16:redeploy failed: Deployment has failed: null

here my code:

```
<profile>
    <id>payara-remote</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>deployAll</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
               <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>${servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the Payara customized version of the Maven Cargo plugin.

version: 1.8.4-payara-p1 (https://github.com/payara/Payara_PatchedProjects/tree/master/org/codehaus/cargo)

https://github.com/payara/Payara_PatchedProjects/ can be used as Maven repository in your project.

Rudy

Comment: Hi Rudy

I have used this version of cargo, to deploy on a deployment group,  but I am getting this error, even though I did not change any of my configuration, any idea?


`There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [glassfish4x], type = [installed]], configuration type [existing]).`

Comment: You can have a look at https://blog.payara.fish/deploying-to-payara-deployment-group-using-the-maven-cargo-plugin, open a GitHub ticket or start a topic on the https://forum.payara.fish/ if you still have issues.